# Can I build a 100,000 pages website with Craft?

Tags: entry, structure

I want to build a fairly large website (over 1000,000 pages and even more users) and I was wandering if Craft was made for large websites or should I look somewhere else?

Do you know any examples of large websites built with Craft CMS?

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to Craft Stack Exchange! Despite being a slightly higher number, this is basically a duplicate of the question noted above... We'll go ahead and close it as a dupe.